# Getting error with Weatherlib API Android

Tags: android, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

I have tried to use directly activity given here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/survivingwithandroid/d671961572899cb8f4b4/raw/MyActivity.java

I have just copied weatherlib jar into my build path libs and copied the above activity to my project with required manifest permission. Yet, my sdk says-  create a class WeatherDefaultClient at this line -

```
 import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.okhttp.WeatherDefaultClient;
```

So how do I fix this?

Comment: I have found that jar is missing -  com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client in its lib package. How can i get it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

You should use Android Studio and import the project using gradle dependency. There is a sample project to use.

Comment: and I have this issue now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481420/unable-to-execute-activity-in-android-for-weatherlib